# Why do I need to copy libraries in lib folder if I define an user library in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, shared-libraries

I created a "dynamic web project" in eclipse and I added to the build path the requested libraries using a "user library". Why it is not sufficient to run the application and I need to copy the libraries in the lib folder of the project?

I understand that it should be a very simple concept, it should be connected on how eclipse and the server store libraries, but I can't find a simple answer.

Comment: What do you mean with _the lib folder of the project_? `WEB-INF/lib`? Have you checked the user library in the Order and Export tab of Java build path?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to end up inside "Web App Libraries" (as seen via *Java Build Path > Libraries*) in order to be present in the runtime classpath as well instead of only the compiletime classpath as you've currently apparently configured. The compiletime classpath is used when you write and compile code. The runtime classpath is used when the code is actually executed on server. Normally, user libraries are already manually supplied external to the webapp and server, e.g. via server configuration. But in your case this is apparently not the case.

One way to get an user library in runtime classpath of a webapp as well with help of Eclipse, the user library needs to be added in the "Deployment Assembly" section as well.

[image]